Magento 2: updateCustomerV2 graphQl
when i am passing value to taxvat variable NULL i am getting syntax error and if i am paasing value to it, it working proper but my requirement is accept the null value as well

when i am checking the log i am getting this kind of error

any help will be appreciate

may be null value is wont accept pass the empty string

worked for me(Magento2.4.3), try with this schema
mutation {
updateCustomerV2(input: {taxvat:null,date_of_birth:"01-02-1999"}) {
customer {
taxvat
}
}
}

